# Updating Ubuntu

Tags: upgrade, partitioning

I installed 9.04 from a disc but apparently need to download a new image then burn a CD to get n upgrade to later versions (v12) as there is no supported upgrade from 9.04.

When I try to download the latest version I find my partition hasn't got sufficient space, but have no idea if (or how) I can resize the partition to store the image before I can burn the CD to update my version. Caught in a bit of a viscious circle here!

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Can you please give us some additional information on your hardware, harddisks, partitions, other operating systems? To do so please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/190451/edit) your question for additions.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to download and burn it on some other PC. Other way is to use **GParted** software to resize your partitions, or you could just make more free space by saving your stuff on CD/DVD, external disk or similar.